# What's a Unix command which will output a list of files in a folder to a text file?

Tags: command-line, unix, osx-leopard, filenames

I'm on a Mac with [Mac OS X v10.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard). I'm using [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh), but I could use [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) if it'd help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ls -1 /directory/you/want/to/list > ~/Desktop/filelist.txt
```

which will redirect the output of `ls -1` (or `ls -l` or whatever you want) to the file ~/Desktop/filelist.txt. Using `>` for redirecting outpiut works for every command, btw. Just google about "input output redirection" (or see this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)).

Comment: When its output is redirected, `ls` automatically uses single-column output mode, so the `-1` above is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

`ls "path/to/folder/" > file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The shell builtin "echo" on its own suffices for this:

```
echo * > file.txt
```